# How to distinguish two PATCH operations for the same enity

Tags: http, patch

I have to implement a REST API endpoint for resource update. But there are two possibilities of update - with and without additional operations. How to handle it?

My API (name it just "API") is going to call a "System" where resource is located. API should handle two kinds of an update call:
A) with check-out/check-in
B) without check-out/check-in

(check-out and check-in are operation which setups/tears Documents during update)

For A) it should look like this:

1. User calls an API with "update with check-out/check-in"
2. API calls System with check-out request
3. API calls System with update data
4. API calls with check-in request.

For B) it should look like this:

1. User calls an API with "update without check-out/check-in"
2. API calls system with update data.

How should I design my API?
My idea is to user PATCH method, because only changed data will be sent:

PATCH: `/documents/{documentId}`

But how to pass information defining if check-out/check-in should be run or not?

I was thinking about query param, like this:

PATCH: `/documents/{documentId}&checkOut=true`
But as far I know query params should be used to pass more details defining resource.

Or should I implement two endpoints? Like this:

For A): PATCH: `/documents/{documentId}`

For B): PATCH: `/documents/{documentId}/withoutCheckOut`